# Pattern matching using regular expressions in a character string

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of a large number of character strings comprised of 0, 1, and N. Here are a few examples:

```
a = "10000000011111111"
b = "11111111111111111"
c = "11111110000000NNN"
d = "00000000000000000"
e = "00000001111111111"
f = "11111000000000000"
```

Im looking for a way of identifying strings that consist only of both '0' and '1' with no 'N'present. My ultimate goal is to substitute into my original data frame 'REC'in the places where this situation occurs. Similar to what was done in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911522/pattern-matching-in-a-data-frame-context).

The result from my above data would be:

```
a = "REC"
b = "11111111111111111"
c = "11111110000000NNN"
d = "00000000000000000"
e = "REC"
f = "REC"
```

The main strategy Ive employed (guided by the responses from the previous question) to achieve my goal uses `gsub` but I cant get a regex that will work for my desired output. I've tried too many iterations to try here but here is my most recent function is as follows:

```
markREC <- function(X) {
 gsub(X, pattern = "^(0)+.*(1)+$", 
      replacement = "REC?")}
```

This function would be run on the data frame with `lapply`

The other strategy Ive tried relied on `strsplit` but Im having trouble getting this one to work too. I can provide examples if people would like to see them. I imagine this would be simple for some regex experts out there but after many hours of trying, Id love some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehm I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with your regex.

```
^(0)+.*(1)+$
```

Effectively means :

Start of string, match at least one 0 followed by anything, followed by at least one 1 and the end of the string. So this : 032985472395871 matches :)

`^(?=.*0)(?=.*1)[01]+$` will match only when the complete string consists for 0's and 1's and there is at least one 0 and at least one 1.

```
// ^(?=.*0)(?=.*1)[01]+$
// 
// Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*0)»
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//    Match the character “0” literally «0»
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*1)»
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//    Match the character “1” literally «1»
// Match a single character present in the list “01” «[01]+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: this doesnt quite work because it picks up strings that have only 0 or only 1 which id like to exclude from this group. Ive edited the question with my desired output.

Comment: @SamGlobus Actually this works perfectly. I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: yes just to strings similar to the ones in the double quotes. The strings will be in a data frame though and will be of different lengths.

Comment: This works great! All I needed to do was turn on perl regex for this function. Thank you!

Comment: @SamGlobus You know what they say, there is more than one way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

To match strings containing only `0` and `1` (and not strings containing only `0` or `1`), you could do:

```
grepl("^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", <string>)
```

For a few of your examples:

```
> grepl("^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", a)
[1] TRUE

> grepl("^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", b)
[1] FALSE

> grepl("^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", c)
[1] FALSE
```

Now plugging this into `gsub`:

```
> gsub(a, pattern="^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", replacement="REC")
[1] "REC"

> gsub(b, pattern="^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", replacement="REC")
[1] "11111111111111111"

> gsub(c, pattern="^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", replacement="REC")
[1] "11111110000000NNN"

> gsub(d, pattern="^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", replacement="REC")
[1] "00000000000000000"

> gsub(e, pattern="^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", replacement="REC")
[1] "REC"

> gsub(f, pattern="^((0)+(1)+(0|1)+)|((1)+(0)+(0|1)+)$", replacement="REC")
[1] "REC"
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper regex is:

```
"[^N]*"
```

I believe. This will match a string of any length unless it contains an N.

Comment: This also matches "" = empty string.

Comment: Well an empty string is still a string isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`^([01]*)[^01]+([01]*)$`

Matches start of string, followed by 0 or more 0/1's, followed by at least 1 character which isnt 0/1, followed by 0 or more 0/1's (followed by end of string)

Comment: This does not match 1111111111111 = not what the op wants.

Comment: you're right, my bad :)  I was too busy focusing on the 'N' aspect, I didnt notice that it should not match strings consisting only of 1's